# ListView in TabHost scroll/click problems

Tags: android, scroll, android-listview, android-tabhost

I have a strange problem that recently appeared. At first I was loading all items in my ListView. It was scrolling all fine. Items were clickable and all was working fine.

Then in the getView of my adapter I added that:

```
if(pos == getCount() - 1){
    Log.i("Load", "Load database");
    load_database(getCount(), 5);
}
```

and here is load_database()

```
private void load_database(long offset, long count) {
    ArrayList<VKContent> objs = BaseApplication.db.get_all(Message.class, MessageHandler.COLUMN_MAILBOX + " = " + mailbox, count, offset);
    for(VKContent obj: objs){
        adp.add((Message)obj);
    }
}
```

The problem appeared right after that. On load it calls load_database once and everything is nice. ListView works fine. Clicks are handled. But once I reach "pos == getCount() - 1". It loads new data but it is now impossible to click items. When I scroll and do a flinch, a touch on the screen won't stop the flinch. When I try to scroll during a flinch it doesn't have any effect until the flinch stopped.

If I switch to a different Tab the listview behavior is restored. If I try use my scroll ball to focus items, the normal behavior come back too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@android:id/tabhost"> 

     <LinearLayout 
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent">

         <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

         <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <ListView android:id="@+id/lv"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:clickable="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
         </FrameLayout> 
     </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**Edit**

I did try to invalidate(), forceLayout(), requestLayout(), isFocusable()... bringToFront... and others after load_database. But nothing helped.

**Edit2**
Almost forgot that piece of code.

```
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

For some reasons, there is a problem with TabHost. My ListView is shared by all tabs. When the view is first loaded it didn't display anything. So I had to switch from second to first tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed my problem, after looking if it worked without the tabHost, I realized it still didn't work. So looking at old code, I realized that my lazy load function was in fact calling a download thread which was run in background then back on the uiThread after the download has been finished.

The difference with the above code is that load_database isn't runned in a different thread. It's runned from the getView function which is a function of my adapter. In other word, it apparently break the listview to update the adapter in getView.

my current fix isn't the best one but for now it does the job. In the futur.

```
if(pos == getCount() - 1){
    MessagesActivity.this.load_more = true;
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();

    if(load_more == true || adp.getCount() == 0){
        load_more = false;
        load_database(adp.getCount(), 5);
    }
}
```

that way, the load_database is never runned from getView. And my adapter update the listview without problem.